# Regain 3DES ECB key, assuming I have both encrypted and decrypted text

Tags: des, ecb, 3des

Let's assume I've encrypted some text with some 24-byte key using 3DES in ECB mode. Is it possible to regain the key if I have both encrypted and decrypted text? (Excluding bruteforce.)

Comment: That would amount to divination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not practically possible. There are [several attacks](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.119.1761&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that are slightly faster than bruteforcing $2^{112}$ key candidates, but this is only a small factor. In some sense, they are bruteforce-like, since they require $2^{113}$ *smaller* steps.

Comment: There are $2^{168}$ possible keys for 24 byte 3DES. It is possible to attack such key with around $2^{112}$ steps, which saves time compares to brute forcing all the possible keys. (But it is still unpractical.)